# Adobe Flex: Accessing Particular Field From XMLList

Tags: xml, apache-flex, google-maps

I currently have data that's returned from my database and has been stored in an XMLList. In the result handler from the database has a loop that puts markers on a Google Map, with custom icons depending on type. When I click the marker it opens an info window and displays HTML containing data from the XMLList. I also want the clicking of the marker to pass data to a label I have, but I can't seem to.
Outside of this function I have declared the following:
`var dict=new flash.utils.Dictionary();`

Here's the code I have so far:

`protected function getBusiness_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var xml:XML = new XML(event.result as String);
                testList = xml.user;`

```
            for (var i:int=0; i<testList.length(); i++) 
            {

                if (testList[i].type=="Hotel") 
                {
                    var bm:Bitmap = new Hotel as Bitmap;
                }
                else 
                {
                    var bm:Bitmap = new Hostel as Bitmap;
                }

                var html:String = "<b>" + testList[i].name + "</b><br/>" + testList[i].street + "<br/>" + testList[i].city + "<br/>" + testList[i].country + ", " + testList[i].postcode;



                var testMarker:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(testList[i].latitude,testList[i].longitude),
                    new MarkerOptions({icon:bm, iconOffset: new Point (-23, -44)}));
                testMarker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MapMouseEvent):void {
                    Marker(e.currentTarget).openInfoWindow(new InfoWindowOptions({contentHTML:dict[e.currentTarget]}));
                });
                dict[testMarker] = html;

                Map.addOverlay(testMarker);
            }

        }
```

That code works, it just allows my to display all markers based on their latitude/longitude and then when I click the marker it displays the information correctly. Within the click function I have added `testLabel.text = testList.name;` and it returned all of the XML  tags, but I don't know how to access a specific one. I tried `testLabel.text = testList[i].name;` and it gave an error saying `Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties`. I also tried `testLabel.text = testList[e.currentTarget].name` and nothing showed up in my label.

I just don't understand how it can access the XML data for the info window when I click the marker, but not for the label. I don't fully understand the dict, but if it means it can only be used once and I have to choose between an info window and returning the function to the label, then I need it to go to the label.
I'm really struggling here so I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: Well there's no XML file, but the PHP writes the XML as it comes back from the database. It looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" ?><map><user>
<userid</userid><name></name><street></street><city></city>
</user></map>

I won't type it all out, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by declaring a new dictionary at the beginning of my file `var nameDict=new flash.utils.Dictionary();` and then in my marker click handler I have the following line `detailName.text = nameDict[e.currentTarget];` then outside of the event (but next to the line that prints the markers is the following line `nameDict[testMarker] = testList[i].name;`.